# How to get div before li using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
<div class="topmsg"></div>
<li>
<div id="message"></div>
....</li>
....</ul>
```

and this list is repeated several times

I could get the div inside the li like this:

```
li.children('div#message').hide();
```

Any ideas on how to get the topmsg using jquery or JS?

Comment: If your HTML looks like that, you need a crash course in HTML.

Comment: This HTML is valid? No. You cannot nest div inside ul.

Comment: And, ID's are unique, so you'd just do `$('#topmsg')`

Comment: Please use close tags, they are feeling rather left out in your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the problems with your HTML.

As you have an ID on the div you want to select, you should just be able to use the # id selector.

```
$('#topmsg')...
```

If you have multiple things with the id of `topmsg` then you really need to reform your HTML so that you don't.

Id is short for "identifier" and should be unique in a document - it is used to uniquely identify the node.

**EDIT after `topmsg` changed from id to class:**

Having changed `topmsg` to be a class, then once you have the `LI` that contains the message you're interested in you can traverse it with a `parent` and then a `find`.

E.g.

```
// Get the LI that contains the message DIV
var messageLi = $('#message').parent();

// Hide it
messageLi.hide();

// Get the 'topmsg' relating to that LI 
messageLi.parent().find('.topmsg').hide();
```

Comment: You are right, I changed the top div to class and the second one remains as ID. Please see the edited code above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it will get the div relative from the li.

```
var topmsg = $(li).parent();
```

Comment: li is not contained in this div, it is directly above that. this is not working. any suggestions?

Comment: well thanks for editing your question that clearly had html code that showed that the li is inside the div and then crying "It don't works". However if the div really has an id just use $('#topmsg') as stated by the other answer.